# How to modify an existing excel file spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am working in a project using spring framework,
I have created an excel file,filled it with database data  and made possible to download it using a button.
But now I want that after the user pushes a button he can select the existing excel file ,modify it and save the modified file to database.
Controller class for 'importing' excel file looks like this,but now I want to do the things above(export the modified excel file)?

```
 @Controller
 public class ExcelController {

 @Autowired
 ContactsServiceI contactsService;

 @PostMapping("importExcel")
 public String AppearExcel(Contact contact, Model model) {

    List<Contact> contacts = contactsService.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("fileName", 
    contactsService.writeToExcelFile(contacts));

    return "importExcel";
}
```

Comment: read the excel -> fill create objects with the data -> save objects to database

Comment: add headers. sample for CSV file:  @RequestMapping(value = "/export", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/csv;charset=ISO-8859-1")  public ResponseEntity<String> export(...) {   ... String filename = "export.csv";
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccessControlExposeHeaders(Collections.singletonList("Content-Disposition"));
        headers.set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(exportedContent, headers, HttpStatus.OK);